# How to validate current password in firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, expo

So I am building a react native expo app and I wanted to reset the password. For now I am just sending the current signed in user an email for reset but I want to do it within the app.

```
function={() => {
            firebase
              .auth()
              .sendPasswordResetEmail(firebase.auth().currentUser.email)
              .then(alert("Please check your email..."))
              .then(auth.signOut())
              .catch(function (e) {
                console.log(e);
              });
          }}
```

With the firebase documentation I know how to reset the password but I think to make it a bit more secure I want to validate the current password. But sadly no idea from the documentation. Any help?